# If $P$ is a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $D_{2n}$ then $N_{D_{2n}}(P)=P$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

> Let $2n= 2^ak$ where $k$ is odd. Prove that the number of Sylow 2-subgroups of $D_{2n}$ is $k$. [Prove that if $P\in Syl_2(D_{2n})$ then $N_{D_{2n}}(P)=P$.]

This question was already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1410582/668308). But none of the answers proved $N_{D_{2n}}(P) = P$. I want to prove the statement by proving $N_{D_{2n}}(P)=P$. How can I prove $N_{D_{2n}}(P) = P$?

Comment: This follows from the fact that the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups is the index of the normalizer of $P$

Comment: @leoli1 I know that. Question is why $N_{D_{2n}}(P)=P$

Comment: $P\subseteq N_{D_{2n}}(P)$ and as they have the same index they are equal.

Comment: @leoli1 I understand $[D_{2n}:P] = k$ but why $[D_{2n}:N_{D_{2n}}(P)] = k$?

Comment: It is proved in the linked answer that the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups is $k$ and by the fact above that this is the index of $N_{D_{2n}}(P)$

Comment: @leoli1 True but my question is to prove the number of Sylow 2-subgroup is $k$ by proving $P = N_{D_{2n}}(P)$ as hint suggested.

Comment: But the point of all of these comments is to point out to you that the answers to the previous question do prove that $P$ is self-normalizing.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes once we know $n_2 = k$. My question is proving $n_2 = k$ by proving $P = N_{D_{2n}}(P)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I just realized that you answered the linked post. Is the fact that 'half of the elements are rotations and the other half is reflections' (comment 2) trivial?

Comment: That depends on what definition of the dihedral group you are using. I think the most common definition is that it is the group of rotations and reflections of a regular $n$-gon, and of course there are $n$ rotations and $n$ reflections.

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm using the same definition. But a subgroup of $D_{2n}$ need not have same number of rotations and reflections. e.g. $\langle r\rangle$ or $\langle rs\rangle$.

Comment: Either the subgroup consists just of rotations (such as $\langle r \rangel$ or else it has the same number of rotations and reflections. In fact $\langle rs \rangle$ does have the same number - it has one of each. Sorry, but that's my final comment in this thread!

Answer (score 0):

[I have expanded this from the original over-brief sketch.]

I think of the group $D_{2n}$ as the group of rotational and reflective symmetries of a regular $n$-gon.

Take any element $x$ of odd prime order $p$; it must be a rotation through $\frac{2\pi}{p}$, and there are only $(p-1)$ of these and they all lie in
$\langle x \rangle$. Hence this subgroup (the only one of its order) is normal in $D_{2n}$.

Suppose that $\langle x \rangle$ normalises $P$.

Let $y\in P$. Then $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy=x^{-1}(y^{-1}xy)\in\langle x \rangle\langle x \rangle=\langle x \rangle$. Also $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy=(x^{-1}y^{-1}x)y\in P P=P$. That is, $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy\in P\cap\langle x\rangle=\{e\}$; so that $x$ and $y$ commute. Hence $\langle x\rangle$ is centralised by a full Sylow-2-subgroup. [If you prefer, $P\leqslant C(\langle x\rangle)$.]

Moreover $\langle x\rangle$ is centralised by the full group of rotations (of order $n$).

Hence $\langle x\rangle$ would be centralised by the whole dihedral group; this is not so, any reflection inverts $x$.

That is, the assumption that $\langle x \rangle$ normalises $P$ cannot hold, and so $N(P)$ cannot be bigger than $P$.

Comment: 1. Why $\langle x\rangle $ is normal in $D_{2n}$? 2. What is the meaning of 'centralizes $P$'? 3. What is the meaning of 'non-central involution'?

Comment: I think the final sentence needs a little more justification. You need $x$ to be inverted by an element of $P$.