# Normalizer of Sylow $2$-subgroup of $D_{2n}$.

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, dihedral-groups

In [Normalizer of a Sylow 2-subgroups of dihedral groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410582/normalizer-of-a-sylow-2-subgroups-of-dihedral-groups?noredirect=1&lq=1) it is proved that the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups of $D_{2n}$ if $2n=2^ak$ where $k$ is odd is $k$ without proving $N_G(P)=P$ if $P$ is Sylow $2$-subgroup of $D_{2n}$. I am trying to prove the fact $N_G(P)=P$ then deduce the number of Sylow$2$-subgroups is $k$. Assume$a,k>1$. If $N_G(P)$ is larger than $P$, then if $g\in N_G(P)$, the order of $g$ must divide $k$, so $g$ is in $\langle r^{2^a} \rangle$. But from here I cannot proceed. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you know the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups, then you can work out the size of the normaliser using the orbit-stabiliser theorem (remember $G$ acts transitively on the set of $p$-subgroups by conjugation, and the normaliser is just the stabiliser of $P$ in this action). This is why this fact is a deduction at the end of the question you link.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen can it work in the reverse way? Or is it not possible if we don't know what is $P$ explicitly?

Comment: My point is that $N_G(P) = P$ follows from the question you link. Given that the number of subgroups is $k$, it follows that the size of $N_G(P)$ must be $2^a$, which is the size of $P$. Since $P \subseteq N_G(P)$ it follows that $P = N_G(P)$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen yes I understand that. But what I am trying to do is the other way round, using $N_G(P)=P$ to deduce the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups is $k$.

Comment: In any group $G$, if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then the number of conjugates of $H$ in $G$ is $[G:N_G(H)]$, the index of the normalizer. Again, that's just the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem applied to the action of $G$ on the set of conjugates of $H$, via conjugation.

Comment: It works the same way.  The number of Sylow subgroups is the index of the normalizer, so if $N_G(P)=P$, it necessarily follows that there are $[G:P]=k$ $2$-Sylow subgroups.

Comment: @RobertShore yes that is true. But how to prove $N_G(P)=P$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes. Now the question is how can you prove $N_G(P)=P$ before knowing there are $k$ conjugates of $P$? From there I already understand how to deduce the number of conjugates.

Comment: Just pick any easy instance of the Sylow and calculate its normalizer directly. E.g., take the subgroup $\langle r^k,s\rangle$, which is a Sylow $2$ subgroup. If $r^i$ normalizes it, conjugating $s$ you get $r^{2i}s$, which requires $k\mid i$. If $r^is$ normalizes, then conjugating $s$ again you get $r^{2i}s$, so again $k\mid i$. So this $2$-Sylow self-normalizes, hence *all* $2$-Sylows self-normalize.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you.